# Grails Runtime Exception with Audit Logging Plugin

Tags: grails

I've deployed my app to tomcat running on EC2 via Cloud Foundry.  The application uses the [Grails Audit Logging Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging)

I'm getting the following runtime error:

```
Error 500: Executing action [save] of controller [com.questern.aoms.CompanyController] caused exception: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: errors for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEvent 
Servlet: grails 
URI: /aoms/grails/company/save.dispatch 
Exception Message: No such property: errors for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEvent 
Caused by: No such property: errors for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEvent 
Class: CompanyController 
At Line: [30]
```

The exception is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: errors for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEvent 

    at $Proxy10.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source) 

    at com.questern.aoms.CompanyController$_closure4.doCall(CompanyController.groovy:30) 

    at com.questern.aoms.CompanyController$_closure4.doCall(CompanyController.groovy)
```

I have added the import statement to the controller CompanyController, but to no avail.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEvent
```

I checked the war file and the AuditLogEvent is include in:

```
aoms-0.1.war\WEB-INF\classes\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\orm\auditable\
```

Any suggestions as to what the problem could be?

Comment: Can you supply the code for CompanyController.groovy line 30 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that maybe your deployment is corrupt. Try exiting all IDE's then run

```
grails clean
```

then

```
grails war
```

or what ever the option to create and deploy.

Sometimes I had found that using STS (Eclipse and the Grails Plugin) the war fails (as you mentioned above)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

AuditLogEvent is a domain class that is included within the audit logging plugin.

You shouldn't need to directly create an instance of this class to get the logging features of the plugin. Let the plugin do the work for you by setting the following field in the domain objects you wish to audit.

```
static auditable = true
```

It looks to me like you might be trying to create and save an instance of the domain class yourself?

> I have added the import statement to
>   the controller CompanyController, but
>   to no avail.

If the domain object you are wanting to audit is "Company" then try just adding the "auditable" field described above and remove all direct references in your project to "AuditLogEvent".

Comment: Thanks for the response.
There are no direct references to AuditLogEvent in my code.  The inclusion of the import was something I seen in the FAQ at http://www.grails.org/plugin/audit-logging.  I think I have implemented Audit Logging as instructed in the documentation and as you have outlined above.